# Tried using NavigationEvents. But getting error 'withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator.'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm getting the error

> withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation
> from props or context.

I am using **NavigationEvents** so that my screen gets re-rendered even when back button is used since I cant use componentDidMount as the screen is already in the stack.
But when using **NavigationEvents** I am getting the above error I am new to coding please help me out

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuhkR.jpg)

Location.js

Its a screen component imported in the App.js file given below but still i am receiving this error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';


export default class Location extends Component {
 onRenderHandler = () => {
   //some function to be called once the screen renders
}

 render () {
  return (
    <View>
      <NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => onRenderHandler()} />
      //body of the render function
    </View>
}
```

App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,StatusBar
} from "react-native";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import theme from "./theme"

import Introduction from "/screens/Introduction";
import Location from "/screens/Location";

import SearchLocation from "/screens/SearchLocation";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render(){
    return (  
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#61dafb"/>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Introduction">
            <Stack.Screen name="Introduction" component={Introduction} options={{ headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Location" component={Location} options={{ headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="SearchLocation" component={SearchLocation} options={{ headerShown: false, animationEnabled: false }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can only use `NavigationEvents` in screen component

Comment: Its actually a screen component. I have edited my question and has added the app.js file, there the location.js is imported and it is a screen component

Comment: What version of `react-navigation` are you using?

Comment: It seems that you're using APIs from both 4.x and 5.x